# CodeSign on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, codesign, bundle-identifier

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign <CertSHA1> --requirements ="designated => identifier org.my-app" /Users/AirWatch/Desktop/MyApp.app/
```

I am trying to codesign my app, named "MyApp.app" using CodeSign command. Bundle identifier for my app is "org.my-app". Instead of "CertSHA1" in the command given above, I am giving my certificate's valid SHA1.

The codeSign command fails because of the hyphen in my bundle identifier. It all works fine if I dont have a hyphen in my bundle identifier. Which is the correct way to execute this command when I have a hyphen for my bundle ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) utility to re-sign your app.

I have tried a bundle id with hyphen and it works fine.